# Should I cache everything

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I'm very close to finishing my application. I'm currently using file cache on laravel to cache basically all of the data that is saved in my tables every time a record is saved, updated or deleted. These tables over a period of time perhaps in 3 years or less will have over 2 million records. I was wondering if there are any pitfalls that I need to be aware of in file caching all of my records. Does anyone foresee a problem with file-caching hundreds of thousands of records over a period of time?

Currently, the way how my cache system works is when I save a new record, delete or make an update to a record it resets the cache for the table/record in question. Each of my tables/and most records has it's own cache. Does anyone foresee any problems with this design with a very large database?

Regards,
Darren

Comment: How are you storing your cache? I mean, for each user? Or the entire table and then add where condition based on the requirements?

Answer (score 5):

You have millions of data, which is a bit concerning if the application has high hits per second. In that case, more hits mean increased disk IO. Any bottleneck in the disk IO should impact the overall performance of the application.

From my personal experience, the best approach is to decide which data should be cached and which should not, what layers and architecture of caching should be used, etc. For example, you may not want to cache any data that is very dynamic. For instance, user carts, balance, view count, etc. As these data are always changing, caching them usually results in (close to) doubling the resource intake rather than increasing the actual throughput in practical scenarios. If a set of data is rarely fetched, it may not need caching at all.

On the other hand, if some part of your data has a very high hit ratio, for instance, home page elements, top posts, best-selling products, etc. then those should be cached using a fast and high availability caching mechanism such as object stores. In this way, high demand can be met in case of thousands of concurrent hits for those data without impacting the disk IO or database performance.

Simply put, different segments of the application data may or may not need different approaches for caching.

Comment: Good day, sir. Sorry about the late. So basically you're saying that information that is very dynamic(changes very often) shouldn't be cached but rather accessed from a database and the information that doesn't change often should be cache?